# Yeoman's angular-fullstack has jpegtran-bin errors and 3 fails

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I got Yeoman's [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) and ran `yo angular-fullstack` (without Heroku), but then I got these failures and errors:

```
  3 failing

  1) jpegtran should successfully proxy jpegtran:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
      at null.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/fs_a/node_modules/jpegtran-bin/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:165:14)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)

  2) jpegtran should minify a .jpg:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
      at null.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/fs_a/node_modules/jpegtran-bin/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:165:14)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)

  3) jpegtran "after all" hook:
     Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'test/minified.jpg'
      at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:760:18)
      at Context.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/fs_a/node_modules/jpegtran-bin/test/test-path.js:10:6)
      at Hook.Runnable.run (/home/ubuntu/fs_a/node_modules/jpegtran-bin/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:211:32)
      at next (/home/ubuntu/fs_a/node_modules/jpegtran-bin/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:246:10)
      at Object._onImmediate (/home/ubuntu/fs_a/node_modules/jpegtran-bin/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:258:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)



/home/ubuntu/fs_a/node_modules/jpegtran-bin/build.js:70
                        throw err;
                              ^
Error: Command failed: configure: error: no nasm (Netwide Assembler) found

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:637:15)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

and then:

```
npm ERR! jpegtran-bin@0.2.0 postinstall: `node pre-build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the jpegtran-bin@0.2.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the jpegtran-bin package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node pre-build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via: 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls jpegtran-bin
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-54-virtual
npm ERR! command "/home/ubuntu/local/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/fs_a
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

I did find jpegtran-bin's github and found a [similar issue](https://github.com/yeoman/node-jpegtran-bin/issues/17), which ended with "we're going to include instructions on how to compile manually."

What should I do in the mean time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue and I updated both yeoman and my Generators and it solved the issue for me.

try running `npm update -g yo` and then run `yo` and select the option to update generators.

**Note:** if you are using an older version of node (< 1.2.10) you have to update bower and grunt-cli separately and make sure its the global version you are updating and not a local version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a discussion with the developer for angular-fullstack and he suggested me to do the following because I had problems with mongoose and jpegtran, as well as I did not have a MongoDB server. Angular-fullstack only connects to Mongodb, it doesn't install it for you with the package.

1. `yo angular-fullstack --skip-install`
2. change the following in package.json:

   ```
   ...
   "mongoose": "latest"
   ...
   "jpegtran-bin": "latest"
   ```
3. `bower install`
4. `npm install`
5. get MongoDB somehow (either [install it on my Ubuntu machine](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) or get it hosted from MongoLab or MongoHQ)

But you can just update the generator like [jonnieM suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22199032/3290121) since at the [end of the discussion with angular-fullstack's developer](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/107), he fixed the mongoose and jpegtran issues in angular-fullstack..